# Passing values to activities and reciveving them in url

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to receive an integer in url.

This how i pass value from one activity to another:

```
private void displayCategoriesInformation(CategoriesModel categoriesModel) {
    //get references to your views
    TextView tvCategoryId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCategoryId);

    final int categoryId = categoriesModel.getId();


    //set values from your categoriesModel java object to textView
    tvCategoryId.setText("Id :  " + categoriesModel.getId());

    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Categories.this, SubCategories.class);
            intent.putExtra("parameter_name", categoryId);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

in **SubCategory.class** i receive it like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.row_subcategory);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int recivedId = intent.getIntExtra("parameter_name", 2);

    TextView tvRecivedId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRecivedId);
    tvRecivedId.setText("recivedId" + recivedId);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait.....");

    spinnerFood = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinFood);
    okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOk);
    // spinner item select listener
    spinnerFood.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    new JSONTask().execute("http://146.185.178.83/resttest/subCategories");
}
```

now the value is stored in the variable recivedId which is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4
what i want to do is execute this JSONTask url like this

```
new JSONTask().execute("http://146.185.178.83/resttest/categories/recivedId/subCategories");
```

so the end url would look like this http://146.185.178.83/resttest/categories/1/subcategories/

how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String url = "http://146.185.178.83/resttest/categories/" + recivedId  +"/subcategories/";
new JSONTask().execute(url);
```